# SIMILE's timeline and google calendar using JSON instead of XML

Tags: xml, json, timeline, simile

Hello:
I am trying to use the JavaScript library timeline from SIMILE. So far I have gotten my timeline to work if the data comes from a XML file.

```
Timeline.loadXML("example.xml", function(xml, url) { eventSource.loadXML(xml, url); });
```

However, I want to get data from a JSON file instead of an XML file.

Thanks a lot for your help.
PS: I am still a rookie in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured this out for a project this weekend by checking out the source of [the example Cubism timeline on the wiki](http://simile-widgets.googlecode.com/svn/timeline/tags/latest/src/webapp/examples/cubism/cubism.html).

What you see in that sourcecode is the following:

```
tl.loadJSON("cubism.js?"+ (new Date().getTime()), function(json, url) {
  eventSource.loadJSON(json, url);
});
```

There are a few things to note about this. First, `tl` is your `Timeline.create(...)` object. Second, the `?` and `new Date` stuff appended to the JSON filename ensure a unique URL on each call to prevent JSON caching.

Comment: It is confusing the way SIMLE's folks advise to use JSON, but they dont give a clear example.

Comment: Were you able to understand the answer I provided? For me, it was a drop-in replacement for the XML handling code you provided.

Comment: Can you open up a javascript console on the page an see if there are any error messages? (In Safari/Chrome, you need to open up Web Inspector and then go to the Console tab. In Firefox, you can check errors in the Error Console, but installing Firebug gives you a nice full console.)